# How to store mathematical symbols?

Tags: sql, .net, angularjs, .net-core

When I paste a mathematical equation in text box, it is working fine but moment I save it special characters like square, angle etc. are converted to random alphanumeric char.

My project is on `.NET Core` + `SQL (SSMS)` + `angularjs`.

What should be done to handle that as my project is for kids solving math problems online. Hence, I need to deal with all possible mathematical expressions.

And I have checked, its breaking in .NET but I don't know may be SQL server would also behave same even if it is handled in .NET!

Comment: Which RDBMS you're using? eg: SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL ...

Comment: What is the data type of the column? `char` or `varchar` only store basic ASCII characters. For Unicode, you will need `nchar` or `nvarchar`.

Comment: @Sami its ssms (sql server)

Comment: @daShier column type is nvarchar

Comment: If you inspect the HTTP traffic between your front-end and your back-end, can you share with us the encoding (charset) (`UTF-8`, `ISO-8859-1`, etc.)

Comment: Thanks everyone, It is working now but there is some other issue which I will ask in a separate question. As of now, whatever sign a normal text box is showing properly are being saved as it is too. No random value appends in fetching data back.

Comment: @Matthew, content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8